# How do I send empty array value using PHP in cURL request?

Tags: php, rest, post, curl

There is a REST API built in JAVA, which accepts an empty array as a request parameter. Without this parameter, API returns empty response. I don't know the significance of sending this empty parameter as I've not built this API. Request should be like this to get proper response from API.

```
//Post data 
$data = array('fieldValues'=>array(),'token'=>'XXXxXX7.......');

$postUrl = 'http://<REST API URL>/<service url>';
$postdata = http_build_query(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// in real life you should use something like:
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
          $postdata);

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
echo $server_output;
exit;
```

My problem is `http_build_query` is escaping `fieldValues` from the CURL post fields. How do I make it included in the post data?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `http_build_query` strips out empty arrays.  You can either reimplement the function to include empty arrays or you can manually add the empty array to the post data.